# How to pass retrieved data to editText?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, textview, cursor

Good day everyone. Can someone tell me how can I retrieve the data from `SQLite` to `editText`?  I have referred to [Android::Data are not retrieving to EditText field through Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19099789/androiddata-are-not-retrieving-to-edittext-field-through-database) but it not working for me..

**DisplayData.java**

```
private void BuildTable(String names,String date1)
    {
        final String name = names;
        final String date=date1;
        sqlcon.open();
        Cursor c = sqlcon.readEntry(name);

        int rows = c.getCount();
        int cols = c.getColumnCount();

        c.moveToFirst();

        TableRow rowDayLabels=new TableRow(this);
        TextView weather=new TextView(this);
        weather.setText("Weather");
        weather.setTypeface(Typeface.SERIF, Typeface.BOLD);

        TextView dater=new TextView(this);
        dater.setText("Date");
        dater.setTypeface(Typeface.SERIF, Typeface.BOLD);

        TextView status=new TextView(this);
        status.setText("Status");
        status.setTypeface(Typeface.SERIF, Typeface.BOLD);

        TextView timeIn=new TextView(this);
        timeIn.setText("Time In");
        timeIn.setTypeface(Typeface.SERIF, Typeface.BOLD);

        TextView timeOut=new TextView(this);
        timeOut.setText("Time Out");
        timeOut.setTypeface(Typeface.SERIF, Typeface.BOLD);

        rowDayLabels.addView(weather);
        rowDayLabels.addView(dater);
        rowDayLabels.addView(status);
        rowDayLabels.addView(timeIn);
        rowDayLabels.addView(timeOut);
        table_layout.addView(rowDayLabels);


        // outer for loop



        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {

            TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
            row.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            // inner for loop
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {

                TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                tv.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
                ));
               // tv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cell_shape);
                tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                tv.setTextSize(18);
                tv.setPadding(0, 5, 0, 5);

                tv.setText(c.getString(j));

                row.addView(tv);
                row.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);

                row.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(DisplayData.this, UpdatePage.class);
                        intent.putExtra("name", name);
                        intent.putExtra("date",date);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });

            }

            c.moveToNext();

            table_layout.addView(row);


        }
        sqlcon.close();
    }

        }
```

**UpdateDetails.java**

```
package com.example.project.project;

import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.project.project.API.InfoAPI;
import com.example.project.project.TimeSheet.Details;
import com.example.project.project.TimeSheet.Force;
import com.example.project.project.TimeSheet.Info;
import com.example.project.project.database.MyDatabaseHelper;

public class UpdatePage extends AppCompatActivity {
    InfoAPI sqlcon;
    private SQLiteDatabase database;
    private MyDatabaseHelper dbHelper;
    private Cursor c;


    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        dbHelper = new MyDatabaseHelper(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.updatepage);
        final String name1 = getIntent().getExtras().getString("name");
        final String date = getIntent().getExtras().getString("date");
        RetrievePage(name1, date);
    }


    public void RetrievePage(String name, String date) {
        final String name2 = name;
        final String date2 = date;
        final EditText name3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText9);
        final EditText date3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText12);
        name3.setText(name2);
        date3.setText(date2);
        //final Spinner weather3 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner5);
        //final Spinner status3 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner7);
        final EditText subC3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText17);
        final EditText noP = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText18);
        final EditText noH = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText19);
        final Spinner poject3 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner8);
        database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        c = database.rawQuery("SELECT w.Subcontractors, w.NumberOfPerson, w.NumberOfHours FROM Information i LEFT JOIN WorkForce w ON w.TInfo_id = i.ID WHERE i.Name = ? AND i.Date= ? ",
                new String[]{String.valueOf(name2),String.valueOf(date2)}, null);
        if (c != null) {
            c.moveToFirst();
            while (c.moveToNext()) {
                Info I = new Info();
                Details WD = new Details();

               // String Weather = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MyDatabaseHelper.Weather));
                //String Status = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MyDatabaseHelper.Status));
                String SubC = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(MyDatabaseHelper.Subcontractors));
                String NoP = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(MyDatabaseHelper.NumberOfPerson));
                String NoH = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(MyDatabaseHelper.NumberOfHours));
                Force WF = new Force();
                WF.setSubcontractors(SubC);
                WF.setNoOfPerson(NoP);
                WF.setNoOfHours(NoH);
                subC3.setText(SubC);
                noP.setText(NoP);
                noH.setText(NoH);

            }

        }
        c.close();


    }
    }
```

**Force.java**

```
public class Force {

    private int id1;
    private String subcontractors;
    private String noOfPerson;
    private String noOfHours;

    public void setID(int  id1)
    {
        this.id1=id1;
    }

    public int getID()
    {
        return this.id1;
    }

    public void setSubcontractors(String subcontractors)
    {
        this.subcontractors=subcontractors;
    }

    public String getSubcontractors()
    {
        return this.subcontractors;
    }

    public void setNoOfPerson(String noOfPerson)
    {
        this.noOfPerson=noOfPerson;
    }

    public String getNoOfPerson()
    {
        return this.noOfPerson;
    }

    public void setNoOfHours(String noOfHours)
    {
        this.noOfHours=noOfHours;
    }

    public String getNoOfHours()
    {
        return this.noOfHours;
    }



}
```

Did I miss anything ? Please let me know!  Any suggestions would be great. Thanks

Comment: not working means? any errors in logcat?

Comment: no...and nothing display on the edittext

Comment: `Here's a bunch of code, tell me why it doesn't work.`  That's basically what you're asking.  Have you tried to debug your code and find out where the problem might be?

Comment: may be case you getting blank value or nothing from db it will be better ypu debug understand the problem and then post

Comment: Is there only one row in the table? You are skipping the first result returned `c.moveToFirst();
            while (c.moveToNext()) {` moveToFirst goes to index 0, then moveToMove moves the cursor to index 1

Comment: @RobVoisey see the edited post..The data will display to table layout(DisplayData.java). I had implemented a tableListener, when the row is pressed, it will display all the information based on the name and date to updatePage.java

Comment: Ok, i have removed c.moveToFirst(); but now get Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow. Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.

Comment: I use getColumnIndexOrThrow() and it returns column 'subcontractors' does not exist....But I checked in my sql, it has Subcontractors column....how can I fix this?? Please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are expecting only one row returned in the cursor you shouldn't call moveTofirst and moveToNext immediately before performing your operations. You are moving to the second row in the cursor by calling these functions immediately. My guess is that your cursor has only one row and your code in while loop is not being executed. Error might be here

```
if (c != null) {
   c.moveToFirst();
   while (c.moveToNext()) {
       Info I = new Info();
   }
}
```

You should be doing something like this

```
if (c != null) {
   while (c.moveToNext()) {
       Info I = new Info();
   }
}
```

Comment: Ok, i have removed  c.moveToFirst(); but now get   Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.

Comment: I use getColumnIndexOrThrow() and it returns column 'subcontractors' does not exist....

Comment: Looks like you getColumnIndex( ) is giving you the wrong index. column index is 0 based index of the result set. Make sure c.getColumnIndex(MyDatabaseHelper.Subcontractors) is 0 and 1, 2 for the other two.

Try setting the indexes to 0, 1, 2 and see if it is working.

Comment: How can I set the index? At where?

Comment: String SubC = c.getString(0);

add 1 and 2 for the other two

Comment: Alright , it solved...just change   public static final String Subcontractors="Subcontractors"; in myDatabaseHandler.java :)